# Could a solar system wide government run efficiently for a century?

Tags: space, government, solar-system

I'm currently working on a Space storyline, and it got me thinking. If a dominant civilization based on bio technology took over a system, similar to the [Lylat](http://starfox.wikia.com/wiki/Lylat_System) System, could it run an efficient government for as long as a century?

What would help or impact the system and or the government in this scenario, relating to its to ability govern for a century?

Comment: "an efficient government" seems like an oxymoron. At least, please tell us what you expect this government to be able to do.

Answer (score 1):

I love a good story in a game! It's the most important part! (in my opinion) Now for a government to run efficiently for a century there are two paths. One is it becomes a dictatorship ruling by power for a century till the people rebel. Or if you don't want that to be the story, and you wan't the government to run good. Then what needs to happen is the government needs only to enforce the laws. If a government intervenes with the people it will not go well. So all you wan't it to do is to protect the people. Then you will have a government that can last a long while. The problem is politicians become corrupt over time so the government will half to have term limits and remove old politicians and add new ones! Then you have a government that can last a century at least! I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to happen, you can easily *justify* a century of stability. One solar system is not *much* larger than the United States, or China. The difference between a couple hundred million people and a few dozen billion isn't that great.

If you want it to break down, you can easily *justify* that, too. The first generation of leaders built the institutions, the second generation lived in them but forgot the struggle, the third generation ran them into the ground. A round of hyperpartisanship, or populism, or apathy.